# 'TypeError: currentSubs[i] is not a function' when using ports in Elm 0.19

Tags: elm

I am attempting to send data from Elm 0.19 to JavaScript using ports.

**Edit**: The problem seems to be related to running/building with [elm-app](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app)

In Elm, I declare an outgoing port:

```
port modelToJs : Json.Encode.Value -> Cmd msg
```

which I use in the `update` function to produce a `Cmd` that sends a JSON encoded value to JavaScript.

In JS, I instantiate the Elm app:

```
const app = Elm.Main.init({
  node: document.getElementById('root')
});
```

and register the data handler:

```
app.ports.modelToJs.subscribe(function dataHandler(data) {
    console.log("got from Elm:" + data);
});
```

When `modelToJs` is called, the data is not sent and printed to the console. Instead, I get the following JavasScript runtime error (which Elm claims to avoid by design):

```
TypeError: currentSubs[i] is not a function

var value = _Json_unwrap(converter(cmdList.a));
  2160 |    for (var i = 0; i < currentSubs.length; i++)
  2161 |    {
> 2162 |        currentSubs[i](value);
  2163 |    }
  2164 | }
  2165 | return init;
```

I have also provided a full proof of concept project on GitHub: https://github.com/mpgirro/elm0.19-ports-issue

The repo also contains an image of the error message (sry, I lack the reputation to post images)

Comment: I'm not able to replicate: https://ellie-app.com/58YWRr9XMy5a1

Comment: @bdukes you are right! In Elli it works as expected. The problem seems to be related to running and building with [elm-app](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app)

Comment: Have you checked with debugger what is `currentSubs[i]` if it's not a function?

Comment: @kaskelotti when the error occurs, `currentSubs[i]` (with `i == 0`) is `{}`

Comment: That's the cost of using these "convenient" utilities. "Zero configuration" means zero idea of what's going on when it fails, or you need something slightly different. This is the exact reason why I recommend against using them, and my suggested solution would be to simply not use it.

Answer (score 2):

The error appears to be in `dataHandler.js`.  It currently contains this:

```
function dataHandler(data) {
    console.log("got from Elm:" + data);
}
```

If you declare the function as `export default` the problem goes away:

```
export default function dataHandler(data) {
    console.log("got from Elm:" + data);
}
```